# Sails.js route redirect with a custom policy

Tags: node.js, sails.js, middleware

Situation I want to achieve:

Request to /register runs AuthController.register

Request to /facebook runs AuthController.register but applies a facebook policy before.

I have created a policy in

```
/api/policies/facebook.js
```

like this

```
var graph = require('fbgraph');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

    facebook_token = req.query.facebook_token;
    if(!facebook_token){
        res.send('401',{error:"Missing facebook token"});
    }
    graph.setAccessToken(facebook_token);
    graph.get("me",function(err,graph_res){
      if(err){
        res.send('401',{error:"Facebook authentication error"});
        return;
      }
      else{
        next();      
      }
    });  
};
```

Set it up policies in

```
/config/policies.js
```

like this

```
module.exports.policies = {
   'auth': {
     'facebook': ['facebook']
   }
}
```

I set up my routes like this

```
module.exports.routes = {
   'post /register': 'AuthController.register',
   'post /facebook': 'AuthController.register',
};
```

Now the code in facebook policy doesn't get called. How would I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if policies can work the way you have intended them to. In your current `/config/policies.js` you're telling Sails to run the `facebook.js` policy whenever the AuthController action `facebook` is called. Since you have no such action defined in the controller, the policy never gets run. To policies, it doesn't matter which way the request came from, what matters is which controller action the request is trying to access.

What you could do, however, is to run the policy on every call to `AuthController.register`, and add a line in the policy file to check whether the request came from `/facebook` or not.

/config/policies.js:

```
module.exports.policies = {
    auth': {
    'register': ['facebook']
    }
}
```

/api/policies/facebook.js:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.route.path === '/facebook') {
        facebook_token = req.query.facebook_token;
        if(!facebook_token){
            res.send('401',{error:"Missing facebook token"});
        }
        graph.setAccessToken(facebook_token);
        graph.get("me",function(err,graph_res){
          if(err){
            res.send('401',{error:"Facebook authentication error"});
            return;
          }
          else{
            next();      
          }
        });
    }
    else return next();
};
```